# NodeMCU ESP8266 burnt. What have I done fundamentally wrong here?

Tags: esp8266, motor

So my setup is:

A 12v DR7-12 battery is providing the power for the board through a DC buck converter set to 3.3V connected to the 3.3V pin of the esp8266.

I then am using pins D5 and D6 to control an L298N motor driver, which has it's 12V connected to the battery (not through the board), it's ground to the battery and the IN1 and IN2 pins connected to the D5 and D6 pins.

I've ended up with three dead ESP8266 boards, they heat up and become unresponsive but as far as I know, I'm not putting any power through the board am I? What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: possibly because of no ground connection between ESP8266 and motor driver

Comment: So the ground pin of the board is connected to the buck converter and then the ground of the battery and the L298N is connected to the ground of the battery as well. Do I need to connect the ground of the L298N directly to the ground of the board as well or in place of?

Comment: it should be ok as long as the buck converter output ground is the same as the battery ground ... also, never disconnect the motor driver ground if the battery positive is still connected

Comment: Please set up a proper regulated 3.3V src before burning more (capacitors are always good and a vreg > buck).  The L298N can be pretty aggressive on its current needs so check that from the 3.3v src before using the esp in the middle.

Comment: When things get hot that is because current is flowing, in your case it appears to be to much. Voltage in itself will not do it in but if allowed to push current past the input protection diodes you can fry it very easily.  The input protection diodes are connected to VCC and Ground so the current is pushed into one of those rails, to much voltage pushes it into VCC and can mess up anything else connected to the VCC as well. You need to determine what part is getting hot, if it is the regulator you may be able to replace it. When in doubt insert resistors and measure voltages.

Comment: @Abel as the OP said, the L298N gets its power directly from the battery (12V), not from the buck converter. I aggree that the OP should check if there are regulated 3.3V at the output of the regulater *before* connecting anything!

Comment: *So the ground pin of the board is connected to the buck converter and then the ground of the battery and the L298N is connected to the ground of the battery as well* - just to make sure: is the buck converter's ground connected to the battery ground? In general, all grounds need to be connected!

Comment: @Gil from my understanding the OP is working with the bare esp8266 module rather than a nodeMCU. So the regulator is an external part anyway...

Comment: OOPS since he stated he is using pins D5 and D6 I assumed it was on a board. However my statement was on a chip level. I should have noted that some junctions can burn up and not warm the chip because they are small. In his case since it is getting warm typically it would be protection device on the chip or simply a breakdown of a junction which will still cause current to flow and get hot.

Comment: Thank you very much all for your detailed responses. You were right, I hadn't connected the ground on the output of the buck converter to the other grounds. So the esp8266 was only connected to the buck converter and the L298N was connected the ground of the battery. When I connected all the grounds together, I haven't had a problem. Why is this needed? Do you always tie all the grounds together?